# Empty Recyclebin using c program

Tags: c, command-prompt, recycle-bin

I cant empty my recycle bin using **c program it gives a "file path not specified" error.**
It works perfectly when i past the [command in the command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238953/how-to-empty-recyclebin-through-command-prompt) but not in the c program. 
Even tried running visual studio in administrator mode.

```
int BinFiles()
{   
char folderCommand[]= "rd /s %systemdrive%\$Recycle.bin";
system(folderCommand);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to replace the environment variable with the value in the string you pass to `system`?

Comment: Try using // instead of / and \\ instead of \.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I have to use double backslashes for file-paths in code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328052/why-do-i-have-to-use-double-backslashes-for-file-paths-in-code)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `\` character:

```
int BinFiles()
{   
    char folderCommand[]= "rd /s %systemdrive%\\$Recycle.bin";
    system(folderCommand);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There should be a question like "why are files specified with a single backslash in code not being found" so we can mark all such questions as duplicates to it.

Comment: @sashoalm There probably is, although I couldn't find one. I guess that questions on this don't have the appropriate keywords in the title. If you can't find one you can always change the title of this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
rd /s c:\$Recycle.Bin
```

(In the above command, “c” is your Windows drive)

Then Press Y key

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>rd /s c:\#Recycle.Bin
c:\#Recycle.Bin, Are you sure (Y/N)? Y
```