# Creating file in some folder other than the folder in which source code is there

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

I have the following folder structure:
         /code
            /files
(i.e "files" folder is present inside the "code" folder)
I am trying to create a file(and write in it) using of fstream like this:

```
ofstream out("\files\plsmap.txt");
```

The compiler isn't giving any error, but, no file is being created in the "files" folder. What can be the possible reason for this and also, is there some other way of doing this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote "\files\plsmap.txt".  The leading slash specifies the root directory of your entire file system.  So "\files" is very different from "\code\files".  You could try removing the leading slash, or changing the string so that it contains the full, absolute path to the directory you are trying to write.  You can figure out the absolute path of a directory by running `pwd` in that directory from a terminal.

Besides the misplaced slashes, the other thing to note is that backslashes are special inside C++ strings, and they need to be escaped using a second backslash when you are writing them in your C++ source code:

```
const char * path = "code\\plsmap.txt";
```

Your environment might allow you to use forward slashes instead, which would be easier since they don't need to be escaped.

Comment: There's an exact-duplicate sink for these questions now - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328052/why-do-i-have-to-use-double-backslashes-for-file-paths-in-code. They can be marked as duplicates to that question.