# Batch file for running DiskPart

Tags: command-line, command

I am trying to develop a batch file to run and remove the Hidden partitions in Windows 7, when trying to remove all partitions. Normally I do this line by line in the Command prompt windows, but was trying to figure out how to create a batch file to run and speed this process up..

Here are lines I type in the command prompt.

```
disk part
Rescan
List Disk
Select Disk 3
List Partition
Select Partition 3
Delete Partition Override
```

I have created a BAT file but can only get the first command to work.

Answer (score 18):

It can be really very easy, but when I look at answers of others I think "Why do it the easy way, when you can do it the hard way" :D

Okay, diskpart is terminal application which means it has it's own CLI *(**c**ommand **l**ine **i**nterface)*. That means, that if you want to write a command to the diskpart, you have to write it to the diskpart's own CLI as a stdin *(**st**andar**d in**put)*. This is the reason, why you cannot wirte your commands via batch file, because your diskpart commands are run as next commands for cmd.exe after diskpart exits.

Now we only must "lie" to diskpart and emulate stdin to his CLI.

We can achieve it like this:

```
(echo Rescan
echo List Disk
echo Select Disk 3
echo List Partition
echo Select Partition 3
echo Delete Partition Override
)  | diskpart
pause
```

So, this code above does the following:

1. The echo commands will generate stdout *(**st**andar**d out**put)*. Usually our command-line interpreter, cmd.exe would just print out this stdout on the screen. (You can try that by running *only* the echo commands **with parenthesis** in cmd.exe)
2. Then, using the pipe `|` we redirect stdout of those echo commands into the diskpart application. So the stdout from echo's will now act as stdin for the diskpart application.

So, you run diskpart, diskpart gets input from echo's, similiarly as it would get input from keyboard, and of course it works!

That is all, simple and easy solution!

Answer (score 12):

Place your diskpart commands (the ones you type after typing `diskpart`) in a text file like `script.txt` and call diskpart with the following command.

```
@echo off
diskpart /s script.txt
```

But be very careful that your commands are correct and well tested and don't call the batch file diskpart.

See here for more information: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415

Comment: What happens if you want to create a batch file which enters diskpart, then exits

Comment: @EPOColla Explain exactly what you need to do - because the syntax above exits diskpart when it's done, if the script commands are all correct.

Comment: I am trying to set up a batch file which runs in WinPE. It's going to 1. do all the partition stuff in diskpart. then 2. copy and image then 3. apply the image using imagex. I have no problem running everything using call commands from 2. it's just whenever i have to enter diskpart in a batchfile, it exits when completed. I cannot continue automated. I have to make a second manual call.

Comment: @EPOColla Open a new question and show what you are doing in your code.  Questions are free. :)

Comment: Yeah I will. I didn't think I really had enough for a question before but I do now. :)

Comment: diskpart /s freezes prompt in win 10

Answer (score 3):

Taking inspiration from the answer from @Msprg, one can do this even easier in PowerShell by using a here-string

```bsh
((@"
Rescan
List Disk
Select Disk 3
List Partition
Select Partition 3
Delete Partition Override
"@
)|diskpart)
```

If you needed that to be in a batch file, you could always inject it directly with one of the tricks you can find in other StackOverflow [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609985/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-within-a-windows-batch-file), as well as [this thread](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5526).

e.g.

```bsh
<# :
@PowerShell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command Invoke-Expression $('$args=@(^&{$args} ($input^|?{$_}));'+(${%~f0}^|Out-String)) & @GOTO :EOF
#>
((@"
Rescan
List Disk
Select Disk 3
List Partition
Select Partition 3
Delete Partition Override
"@
)|diskpart)
```

Answer (score 2):

So hey, I know I'm super late to the party, but I've been messing around with Diskpart and scripting, etc for some post-imaging stuff I want to do, and, though it's not a direct solution to your EXACT question, read through it anyways, and I bet you can kludge this into what you need to do: (Yes, it's very kludge-y. I don't care. It exists as ONE file, no external files necessary, and cleans up after itself.)

```
REM SCRIPT TO EXTEND A VOLUME - PICKS THE CORRECT ONE REGARDLESS OF VOLUME CONFIGURATION
REM THE VOLUME AFTER IMAGING WILL ALWAYS BE 39GB IN SIZE SO THAT'S WHAT IT HINGES ON
REM
REM THIS SCRIPT BECAME NECESSARY WHEN RUNNING DISKPART WITH A FIXED SCRIPT DIDN'T WORK 
REM FOR EVERY MACHINE DUE TO DIFFERENT DISK CONFIGURATIONS
REM
REM IT'S NOT PRETTY, BUT IT GETS THE JOB DONE AND CLEANS UP AFTER ITSELF
REM
REM <CHRISTOPHER T####N> 4/27/2016
REM
@ECHO OFF
@CLS
REM
REM GET LIST OF VOLUMES AND EXPORT TO TEXT FILE TO BE RUN AS SCRIPT BY DISKPART
ECHO LIST VOLUME>>C:\VOLLIST.TXT
REM
REM RUN TEXT FILE AS SCRIPT WITH DISKPART THEN EXPORT RESULTS TO NEW TEXT FILE
DISKPART /S C:\VOLLIST.TXT>>C:\VOLTEMP.TXT
REM
REM REMOVE THAT FIRST TEXT FILE WE CREATED
DEL C:\VOLLIST.TXT
REM
REM TAKE THE LIST OF VOLUMES AND GET THE ONE YOU NEED WITH THE FIND COMMAND (MODIFY AS NEEDED)
REM THEN USE THE TOKENS/DELIMS TO GRAB JUST THE VOLUME NUMBER YOU WANT
REM AND CREATE ANOTHER TEXT FILE CONTAINING THE FINAL SCRIPT TO EXTEND THE VOLUME YOU WANT
FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS= " %%A IN ('TYPE C:\VOLTEMP.TXT ^| FIND /I "39 GB"') DO ECHO SELECT VOLUME %%A>>C:\VOLEXT.TXT
REM
REM REMOVE THE SECOND TEXT FILE
DEL C:\VOLTEMP.TXT
REM
REM APPEND ADDITIONAL DISKPART COMMANDS TO THE FINAL TEXT FILE
ECHO EXTEND>>C:\VOLEXT.TXT
REM
REM APPEND ADDITIONAL DISKPART COMMANDS TO THE FINAL TEXT FILE
ECHO EXIT>>C:\VOLEXT.TXT
REM
REM RUN DISKPART USING THE FINAL TEXT FILE AS THE SCRIPT
DISKPART /S C:\VOLEXT.TXT
REM
REM REMOVE THE FINAL TEXT FILE SO NOTHING IS LEFT BEHIND AFTER SCRIPT EXECUTION
DEL C:\VOLEXT.TXT
REM
REM PAUSE SO YOU CAN SEE IF ANYTHING FAILED, AND HOPEFULLY, WHERE
@PAUSE
```

Comment: Is this all from a single batch file?  I'm running this into the command prompt and you have to be in diskpart to be able to use any list volumes.