# How to use a PowerShell function return as a variable in a batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I was trying to use the return from myPowershellScript.ps1 to use as a variable in my batch file.

myPowershellScript.ps1

```
function GetLatestText
{
    return "Hello World"
}
```

I was trying to use the For /F function. There may be a better way.

myBatch.bat

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' powershell -command "\\Rossi2\Shared\myPowershellScript.ps1" ') do set "var=%%a"

echo %var%
```

Desired output, would be to have 'Hello World' output in the cmd window.

I was trying to use the batch file as some old processes use them. For newer processes I do everything in PowerShell and it works fine.

The current output is blank.

Comment: I noticed that if I just create a new .ps1; and on line 1 I type ''Hello World'' it works. But it won't return my function return string. If my Powershell Script had more than one function in it, how would I call the correct function in the batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your syntax for trying to capture output from a PowerShell script from a batch file is correct (assuming *single-line* output from the script),<sup>[1]</sup> except that it it is more robust to use the `-File` parameter of [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI than the `-Command` parameter.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375) for when to use `-File` vs. `-Command`.
- Your problem is with the PowerShell script itself:

  - You're *defining* function `Get-LatestText`, but you're not *calling* it, so your script produces no output.
  - There are three possible solutions:

    - Place an explicit call to `Get-LatestText` *after* the function definition; if you want to pass any arguments received by the script through, use `Get-LatestText @args`
    - Don't define a function at all, and make the function body the script body.
    - If your script contains *multiple* functions, and you want to call *one* of them, selectively: in your PowerShell CLI call, [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) the script file (`. <script>`), and invoke the function afterwards (this *does* require `-Command`):

      ```bash
       for /f "delims=" %%a in (' powershell -Command ". \"\\Rossi2\Shared\myPowershellScript.ps1\"; Get-LatestText" ') do set "var=%%a"

       echo %var%
      ```

---

<sup>[1] `for /f` loops over a command's output *line by line* (ignoring empty lines), so with multiline output only the *last* line would be stored in `%var%` - more effort is needed to handle multiline output.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for explaining in so much detail. I will probably use the 3rd of your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the batch and the powershell in single file (save this as `.bat` ):

```
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"') do set "result=%%a"
    echo PS RESULT: %result%

endlocal
goto :EOF

: end batch / begin powershell #>

function GetLatestText
{
    return "Hello World"
}

write-host GetLatestText
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue I'm trying to avoid is if I need to update the PowerShell script in the future, I don't want to update the .bat.

Comment: This hybrid batch-file/PowerShell-script solution is interesting, but, generally speaking, if (robust) argument-passing must also be supported, an `iex` (`Invoke-Expression`)-based solution falls short - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49063524/45375) for a robust alternative (it doesn't capture the PowerShell script output on the batch-file side, but it could be adapted to do that). As an aside: `write-host GetLatestText` treats `GetLatestText` as a _string literal_. To call function `GetLatestText` and output its result, just use it by itself (no output command needed).