# Powershell Regex to create $Args[*] array manually with -Split()

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am running a powershell command -encoded via a CMD file, because of the way I am running it I have to build out the $Args var from a passed %* from CMD. I do a text replace with CMD before launching at the top of the PS1 code that would end up being something like this:

```
$p='%*'; $Args=$p.Split(" ")
```

This gives me an array with space as a delimiter, but this obviously misses things like "paths with spaces" etc because every word gets split. CMD automatically wraps double quotes (") around each arg with spaces.

I know I can do regex with -Split() instead of .Split(), I could use no regex for one space as shown, or regex for anything in between quotes, but I'm not sure how to do both in one shot.

This is an example using the above method:

```
<# ::
@ECHO OFF
POWERSHELL -nop -ep bypass -c "POWERSHELL -nop -ep bypass -en ([System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes((GC '%~f0' -raw) -Replace('###POWERSHELL BELOW THIS LINE###','$PSScriptRoot=''%~dp0'';$PSCommandPath=''%~f0'';Set-Location ''%~dp0''; $p=''%*''; $Args=$p.Split(""" """)'))))"
GOTO :EOF
#>
###POWERSHELL BELOW THIS LINE###

"There are a total of $($args.count) arguments"
$Args | % { 'arg #{0}: [{1}]' -f ++$i, $_ }

cmd /c pause
```

**UPDATED:**
Found a working solution

```
<# ::
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & FOR %%a IN (%*) DO SET ARGS=!ARGS!%%a,
POWERSHELL -nop -ep bypass -c "POWERSHELL -nop -ep bypass -en ([System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes((GC '%~f0' -raw) -Replace('###POWERSHELL BELOW THIS LINE###','$PSScriptRoot=''%~dp0'';$PSCommandPath=''%~f0'';Set-Location ''%~dp0''; $p=''!ARGS:~0,-1!''; $Args=$p.Split(""",""")'))))"&ENDLOCAL
GOTO :EOF
#>
###POWERSHELL BELOW THIS LINE###

"There are a total of $($args.count) arguments"
$Args | % { 'arg #{0}: [{1}]' -f ++$i, $_ }

cmd /c pause
```

Comment: As an aside: PowerShell has a built-in `pause` command too (no need for `cmd /c pause`): it is a function wrapper around [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host), specifically: `$null = Read-Host 'Press Enter to continue...'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Even trying to embed `%*` inside `"..."` in a batch file can *syntactically break* your command.
- Therefore, you must pass `%*` *unquoted* to [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, which in turn requires use of the `-File` parameter,<sup>[1]</sup> which in turn requires that you create a *temporary copy* of your batch file *with a `.ps1` extension* that you can pass as the `-File` argument to you `powershell.exe` call.

```
<# ::
@echo off & setlocal
set "__thisBatchFile=%~f0"
copy /y "%~f0" "%TEMP%\%~n0.ps1" >NUL && powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%TEMP%\%~n0.ps1" %*
set ec=%ERRORLEVEL% & del "%TEMP%\%~n0.ps1"
exit /b %ec%
#>
###POWERSHELL BELOW THIS LINE###

# Determine the equivalent of $PSScriptRoot, and $PSCommandPath,
# i.e. the directory in which the batch file is located and the
# batch file's full path.
$originalBatchFilePath = $env:__thisBatchFile
$originalBatchFileDir = Split-Path -Parent $originalBatchFilePath

"There are a total of $($args.count) arguments"
$Args | % { 'arg #{0}: [{1}]' -f ++$i, $_ }

pause
```

Note:

- The hybrid file technique, i.e. using a *batch file* (`.cmd` or `.bat`) that contains *embedded PowerShell code* that the batch-file portion of the code automatically invokes via the PowerShell CLI, is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49063524/45375).
- *Character-encoding caveat*:

  - Make sure that your hybrid batch file doesn't contain *verbatim* characters that are *non-ASCII* characters, as that may cause misinterpretations:

    - By default, `cmd.exe` only recognizes *BOM-less* files, which it assumes to be encoded based on the *current console code page*, which defaults to the legacy system locale's *OEM* code page.
      However, such files would be *misinterpreted by PowerShell*.
    - That said, as long as you stick with a *BOM-less* file, you can get away with only the *batch-file part* being restricted to ASCII-range-only characters, as long as the file overall uses an encoding that is automatically recognized *by the PowerShell CLI* - see below.
  - If you *do* need to embed verbatim non-ASCII-range characters (e.g, `ö`) in the *PowerShell part* of the file, choose the following approach:

    - For calling the *Windows PowerShell* CLI (`powershell.exe`), as in this case, save the file using the legacy locale's *ANSI* code page.
    - For calling the [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) CLI (`pwsh.exe`), save the file using *BOM-less UTF-8*, which is the consistent default encoding there.

---

<sup>[1] The `-Command` (`-c`) CLI parameter is *not* a robust option, because it cannot pass arguments through *verbatim* - they are invariably subject to *interpretation as PowerShell code*, which can alter arguments and even break the call.</sup>

Comment: I found a way to pass them back into the array correctly, update in op ;) Don't forget CMD has some tricks up its sleeve as well.

Comment: @PlayLORD-SysOp your solution won't work with complex escaping

Comment: @PlayLORD-SysOp, generally speaking: `cmd.exe` has only painfully obscure, half-broken tricks up its sleeve, and `enabledelayedexpansion` is no exception: it makes passing arguments with verbatim `!` characters all but impossible. Your updated solution is bewilderingly complex, and I doubt that it handles pass-through arguments better than this (comparatively) simple solution. Note that with `-File` PowerShell parses all command-line arguments _verbatim_ (after removal of _syntactic_ `"` chars.), with the only _escaping_ requirement being the need to escape _embedded_ ``"`` chars. as `\"`.

Comment: @PlayLORD-SysOp, to phuclv's point: for instance, your solution breaks with a command line such as `.\yourHybridBatchFile.cmd one "Nat \"King and I\" Cole!" two`, which this solution handles correctly.

Comment: I've decided to mix your method with self elevation and symbolic link. it seems to cover everything for now, thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @PlayLORD-SysOp. Out of curiosity: are you self-elevating solely in order to be able to predictably create a symlink? ( Elevating for that reason alone wouldn't advisable for security reasons) The temporary-file method isn't as elegant (and is slower) than the symlink method, but it should still work as intended.

Comment: @mklement0 I just want to make sure that regardless of whatever type of code is in the script that it runs without issue. The fact that it is unknown at the time of writing makes me want to ensure it works.  Also i found another way, a one liner, without a temp file by AveYo, it can be placed at the top of the file by itself without commenting it out:  @(set "0=%~f0"^)#) & powershell -nop -c iex([io.file]::ReadAllText($env:0)) & GOTO :EOF

Comment: @PlayLORD-SysOp, well, with elevation you're preventing non-admins from running the script, and admins will run it with possibly unneeded privileges. The `-c` (`-Command`) approach prevents you from passing arguments _verbatim_ through, potentially resulting in unwanted interpretation that can break the call - only `-File` can do that.

Comment: Yea im not sure why I keep forgetting that, i never posted the line with the symlink I guess its back to that. Thank you for all your help again, i use this in the last commented out line: (IF EXIST "%temp%\%~n0.ps1" DEL "%temp%\%~n0.ps1" /f /q)&(MKLINK "%temp%\%~n0.ps1" "%~f0">nul)&POWERSHELL -nop -ep bypass -f "%temp%\%~n0.ps1" %*&DEL "%temp%\%~n0.ps1" /f /q&GOTO :EOF