# How do I get PowerShell script path of and inside Batch-Powershell Hybrid script even when the path contains multiple occurrences of Square Brackets?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, path, literals, hybrid

See the below script that I have for renaming Movie files with .mp4 or .mkv extensions:

```
<# ::

@echo off
powershell -c "iex ((Get-Content -LiteralPath '%~f0') -join [Environment]::Newline); iex 'main %*'"
pause && goto :eof
#>

$path = Split-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -Parent
echo $path
## $validExtensions = '.mkv', '.mp4'
## Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path -File |
##     Where-Object Extension -In $validExtensions |
##     Where-Object Length -GT 500mb |
##     Rename-Item -NewName {
##         ($_.BaseName -replace 'MkvHub.com - ' -replace '(?<=1080p|720p).+' -replace '\.', ' ').ToUpper() + $_.Extension
##     }
```

Currently I have commented out the rest of the Powershell code for obvious reason of testing whether the code `Split-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -Parent` or `split-path $myInvocation.myCommand.path` would give us the literal path of this same script during execution or not.

Clearly it doesn't give me the expected path, and instead throws this error:

```
Split-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
At line:7 char:26
+ $path = Split-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -Parent
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Split-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Spli
   tPathCommand

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Also the similar error with `split-path $myInvocation.myCommand.path` too.

As aforementioned I already tried both `split-path $myInvocation.myCommand.path` and `Split-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -Parent`, but none of them are working.

Can anyone help figuring this out ? I have to make this work in hybrid script only...

Comment: Is your question/problem that when using this 'hybrid' methodology, `$PSScriptRoot` does not hold the value of the parent directory of the running batch file? Also, I should mention that `%*` could include doublequotes, which could cause you issues, as those would be nested within the `-c`/`-command` doublequotes.

Comment: I don't know much about how the `$PSScriptRoot` is formed when Powershell command/script is invoked, but it seems that it's losing it's value when used inside Hybrid script for sure.

Comment: Would ensuring your current directory in the batch file was set to the batch file parent not mean that PowerShell inherits it? In that case you could use relative paths or `split` out from `Get-Location`. As a somewhat related side question, what is stopping you from using `%~dp0`/`%~p0` from the batch file, and passing it as an argument, or defining it as a variable to be used as needed by PowerShell?

Comment: There can be inserted below `@echo off` the command line `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` and the command line `set "ScriptPath=%~dp0"`. The string value of the environment variable `ScriptPath` can be accessed from with the PowerShell script code wherever this directory path is needed in the PowerShell script code. Please note that the directory path assigned to the environment variable `ScriptPath` ends always with a backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, the [automatic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables) [`$PSScriptRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psscriptroot) and [`$PSCommandPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pscommandpath) are only defined *inside script files (`*.ps1`)* (and script *module* files (`*.psm1`)).

Since your hybrid batch-file approach relies on invoking [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, by *directly passing source code* to its `-c` (`-Command`) parameter, these variables are therefore *not* defined.

As [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi) suggests, you can set a variable with the batch file's own directory before calling `powershell.exe`, which - due to `cmd.exe` variables also being *environment* variables - the PowerShell code can then access as such, using the [`$env:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Variables) namespace.

However, a *robust* hybrid batch/PowerShell solution requires the use of the `-File` PowerShell CLI parameter in order to correctly handle *pass-through arguments*, which in turn requires creating a *temporary copy of the batch file as a  `.ps1`  file*.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77101389/45375), which combines the `-File` approach with passing the original batch-file path via an environment variable, allowing the PowerShell code to infer the *equivalents* of `$PSScriptRoot` and `$PSCommandPath`.

Comment: My pleasure, @VickyDev; glad to hear it helped.